# What's the preferred way to train a convolutional neural network with variably-sized images?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Potential paths:

- Find the max with and height, and images set excess pixels to 0.
- Crop the images to a standard average size.
- Other?

Comment: actually you should crop to the size of the smallest pic, not average. Otherwise you'll still have variably-sized images.

Comment: Besides zero-padding, replicating the boundaries is also possible, and sometimes more beneficial.

Comment: Padding zeros, replicating boundaries create unnecessary patterns the network may try to learn. Fix an input size and resize all the images to that size.

Answer (score 0):

In tensorflow, I lazy-define the placeholder shape. Ex:

```
input_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(BATCH_SIZE, None, None, CHANNELS))
```

'None' indicates a variable size. This way, I won't lose information due to cropping, or I won't have to add incorrect information by padding.

Comment: padding is not "incorrect information". And in fact, this placeholder tensor will work by adding padding to your model of the largest sent tensor.

Comment: I was not aware of that, and it would worry me if that is the case. What would happen if my batch size is 1? The placeholder will never know what my 'largest' tensor is.